# why doesn't the 'all_members' variable change after adding 1 to `man`?

Tags: c++

I just started programming and I started with C++. I'm learning about variables and was practicing.

I added two variables together and then added 1 to one of them (`man`).
After that, I wanted to show them added together (`all_members`).

But it doesn't count in the `+1` I included. How can I solve this ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int man = 2;
    int women = 1;
    int all_members = man + women;

    cout << "the number of men in this house is: " << man << flush;
    cout << " and the number of women in this house is: " << women << endl;

    cout << "new baby boy!" << endl;

    man = man + 1;

    cout << "now the number of humans present in this house is: " << all_members << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this is the final text that comes up:

```
the number of men in this house is: 2 and the number of women in this house is: 1
new baby boy!
now the number of humans present in this house is: 3
```

Comment: Absolutely a duplicate of _something_. To answer your question OP, assignment for primitives (like integers) is a one-and-done thing, primitives don't change unless you assign something new to them. However, this should be closed because there have been a lot of questions asked just like it.

Comment: @micpap25 You're right, this is almost certainly a dupe of something. However, it can't be closed until someone finds the right target. Please do search for one, and if you find it, go ahead and vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
int all_members = man + women;
```

initializes `all_members` with the value of `man + woman`, with the values that `man` and `woman` have when this code is executed. If at some later point, you change the value of either `man` or `woman`, this has no effect on the value of `all_members`. If you want the value to change, you will need to update that variable again.

---

One way to solve this is to make `all_members` a lambda like this:

```
auto all_members = [&] { return man + women; };
```

Since the lambda captures `man` and `woman` by reference, any changes to these variables will be reflected in calls to this lambda.

Note that `all_members` is no longer an `int`, but a type that returns an `int`. So instead of just saying `all_members`, you have to say `all_members()` to retrieve the value.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KdPnTx).

Comment: or insert `sleep(15552000)` near the end of main() - maybe the value of all_members corresponds to reality when the process comes back to live :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know c++, but I think you have to update the `all_members` variable.

Comment: I don't know how much c++ you know, but this is correct :)

Comment: @cigien I never learned c++, but it's a bit like java so I got the answer.

Comment: That's good :) Fair warning, I would suggest being careful about posting C++ answers when you're guessing at the solution. If you do get it wrong, you're likely to get a lot of downvotes very fast :)